# Giving to FLAUI the command for hit a key combination (such as ALT + F4) changes the keyboard controls

Tags: xunit, specflow, flaui

i'm making an automated test with flaui, it includes

```
Keyboard.Press(VirtualKeyShort.ALT);
Keyboard.Press(VirtualKeyShort.F4);
```

it works fine, but then  my keyboard controls are completely different, for example i'm not able anymore to write using letters because they have different behavior, what i need to do for restore them is by performing again ALT + F4. I also tried using different keyboard but is the same, help pls!!

what i need to do for restore them is by performing again ALT + F4. I also tried using different keyboard but is the same, help pls!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `.TypeSimultaneously()` method, like below:

```
Keyboard.TypeSimultaneously(VirtualKeyShort.ALT, VirtualKeyShort.F4);
```

See the full documentation [here](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI/wiki/Keyboard).